# Missing .NET features in Metro style application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Mostly out of curiosity, I started programming a small "Metro Style" project in Visual Studio 2011, the one that was released in Windows Developer Preview. It combines XAML for the design and C# (in my project) for the code-behind.

The C# experience is mostly identical to the one you get on Visual Studio 2008 with .NET framework 4.0, save for these features that I wasn't able to find :

- **System.Console**, which make debugging a bit more difficult,
- And **System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)**, which is a bit more inconvenient since that's exactly what I needed right now.

So are these features actually missing / disabled, or did I just look in the wrong place ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't have the Preview installed, so I can't check. But here are two thoughts:

1. System.Console is probably not available, because there is no Console in Metro style applications. Check if [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) is available. It writes directly to the Debug window in Visual Studio.
2. Metro style applications are not supposed to block threads for extended durations. Everything that takes more than a few milliseconds should be done in an asynchronous way. Look 
   for some way to execute an asynchronous callback after some time, e.g., a timer. Or you might be able to `await` the end of a time span (like  TaskEx.Delay in the Async CTP).

Comment: All stuff in `TaskEx` is now moved to `Task` proper, so `await Task.Delay(ms)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

For "printf debugging", I suggest that you use `Debug.WriteLine` and/or `Trace.WriteLine` methods from `System.Diagnostics` namespace. They print to the debugger output window - in VS Express that comes in Developer Preview, you'll need to enable that first (Debug -> Windows -> Output).

For `Thread.Sleep`, can you clarify the specific scenario for which you believe it to be needed?

Comment: Thanks, Debug.Write worked. As for Thread.Sleep, I needed it to quickly prototype a loop, but the Task.Delay proposed by the answer above filled the gap nicely.

Comment: Great solution - this is the equivalent of Trace.WriteLine() in WPF in the System.Diagnostics namespace.

Answer (score 6):

http://dougseven.com/2011/09/15/a-bad-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-long-discussions/

My understanding is that it's just a subset; most of what is missing relates to synchronous operations (so I'm not surprised that Thread.Sleep() is gone).  You'll also find things like 'File.Create' cannot be called synchronously.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `Thread.Sleep()`, but you can use `Task.Delay(milliseconds);`

For those wondering what is it useful for, I say I use it in debug to stress async behaviour.